# How to create a table of signs

Tags: tables, mathematics

I'm pretty new to TeX and LaTeX and to learn I'm trying to copy my handwritten notes from my notebook to a LaTeX document.
I feel like I'm starting to understand how LaTeX works, but I'm certainly not that good at using it.

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is the following table

[image]

It is a very basic table of signs, where on the top we have two numbers (-3 and 2) corresponding to the vertical line that divides the cells.
Additionally I would like to add the points as shown in the picture, to show the zeroes.

What I've tried / found so far:

- Creating a table (with `\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c} ... \end{tabular}`) doesn't seems to work, I cannot get the numbers to be aligned to the vertical line as I want.
- [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68802/creating-an-automated-table-of-signs) may be related to mine, but the solution provided is too difficult and far different from what I'm trying to achieve.
- [This one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162157/create-a-tables-of-signs-and-variations-of-function-using-tkz-tab-package) is even more complicated, and adds to much things that for my case are not useful.

Thanks everyone in advance, I hope to enhance my skills with LaTeX / TeX in the upcoming months.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Interesting problem, although I'm not convinced of its pedagogical validity.

Comment: I'm a masochist, obviously copying all my notes to LaTeX isn't the smartest choice ever, but I wanted to give it a try :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not identical to your table, but still quite near.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% tkz-tab hardcodes $0$ for the zeros
\xpatchcmd{\tkzTabLine}{$0$}{$\bullet$}{}{}
% we want solid lines
\tikzset{t style/.style={style=solid}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzTabInit[lgt=2,espcl=2,deltacl=0]
  { /.8, $3(x-2)^2$ /.8, $x+3$ /.8, $p(x)$ /.8}
  {,$-3$,$2$,} % four main references
\tkzTabLine {,+,t,+,z,+,} % seven denotations
\tkzTabLine {,-,z,+,t,+,}
\tkzTabLine {,-,z,+,z,+,}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I do actually like it, and it respects the alignment of the numbers! Wonderful!

Comment: @DenysVitali The manual of `tkz-tab` is in French, but quite readable, particularly for a Swiss, I believe. Not intuitive at first, but there are several examples.

Comment: I do actually have read some parts of it (and I don't have any problem at understanding French), but found it too complicated for my level of knowledge of LaTeX. I'll certainly use that as a reference in the future, that package seems really powerful. (Grazie per l'aiuto!)

Comment: @DenysVitali I had a very good teacher of French in middle school, a few years ago. `;-)`

Comment: Is it easy to evaluate the signs on the fly rather than hard-coded?

Comment: @SingleFighter Not with this package; there is `tablor`, which relies on an external CAS for its working.

Comment: Without the `xpatch` stuff, the table will have zeroes rather than big dots, which is exactly what I was looking for when I found this question (and other people may be looking for).

Answer (score 6):

[image]

above table is drawn with TikZ:

```
\documentclass[ tikz,
                border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, 
             column sep=0cm, row sep=0pt,
     nodes={text width=15mm, align=center, 
            text height=3ex, text depth=1.5ex}]
{
3(x-2)^2    &   +   &   +   &   +   \\
(x+3)       &   -   &   +   &   +   \\
p(x)        &   -   &   +   &   +   \\
};
\foreach \i in {1, 2, 3}
{
\draw  (m-\i-1.north west) -- (m-\i-4.north east);
\draw  (m-1-\i.north east) -- (m-3-\i.south east);
}
\draw   (m-3-1.south west) -- (m-3-4.south east);
%
\node[above] at (m-1-2.north east) {$-3$};
\node[above] at (m-1-3.north east) {$2$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't trust my eyes, hence took a ruler and it is strange the horizontal lines do not seem to be perpendicular to the vertical direction ... the thing looks strangely distorted, like when I take out my glasses.

Comment: ups, not the last image and code, I will correct this immediately

Comment: oops -- that's "hyphen 3" at the top, not "minus 3".

Answer (score 4):

If the *n* columns with the signs always have the same width, and always with `n-1` headers, then a simple trick could be make a multicolumn cell with the headers spaced with `\hfil`:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$}|>{$}l<{$}|>{$}l<{$}|>{$}l<{$}}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$-3$ \hfil 2 \hfil } \\\hline
3(x-2)^2    &   +   &   +   &   +   \\\hline
(x+3)       &   -   &   +   &   +   \\\hline
p(x)        &   -   &   +   &   +   \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using \multicolumn seems simple enough to me. It seems more natural to use  \multicolumn{4}{l}{\phantom{3(x-2)**2 + } $-3$ \phantom{+} 2 }

Answer (score 0):

With french people, I'used **tabvar** to draw table of signs and table of variations when needed. Easy to learn and readable. No Tikz nor Pstricks experience needed.

```
\[\begin{tabvar}{|C|CCCCC|} \hline
x &\quad-\infty & &\quad ...& &\quad+\infty
\\ \hline
f'(x)=...& &\quad-&\quad 0&\quad + &
\\ \hline
\niveau{2}{2}
\TVcenter{f(x)=...}&\quad+\infty  &\quad\decroit &\quad...&\quad\croit&\quad+\infty
\\ \hline
\end{tabvar}\]
%\TVstretch[0pt]{\dfrac{1}{2}} et \TVcenter{f(x)} 
%\addstackgap[5pt]{***} \usepackage{stackengine}
```

Here, a sample to show some tabvar possibilities with a basic LaTex experience.