# Drawing function's sign in a line

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I need a function that, given starting and ending point, some points that can be both included and excluded and a starting sign, it will draw a line, circles in place of those points (black filled if included, white filled if excluded) and the + or - sign. Basically I need something like

[image]

except with `+` signs before and after `0` and `3` and with the ability to choose whether or not those points are included in the domain of the function.

What I currently have is

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{
  arrows,
  decorations,
  calc,
  intersections,
  matrix,
  decorations.pathmorphing,
  spy,
}

\newcommand\signplot[4]{ % start end points signStart
  % Draws a line between #1 and #2
  \draw[shorten <= -1cm, shorten >= -1cm] (#1) -- (#2);

  % Checking whether the first sign is positive or not
  \ifnum1=#4\relax % It starts positive
    % Cycle between the list of points given at which the sign changes
    \foreach \x in #3{
      % Drawing circles with the text
      \coordinate (A) at (#1);
      \coordinate (B) at (\x,0);
      \filldraw[fill=black,draw=black] (A-|B) circle(2pt)
        node[below]{\x};
      % Going through 0->\x (where \x = current coordinate) with a step of 0.3
      \foreach \c in {0,0.3,0.6,...,\x}{
        \coordinate (A1) at ($(A)+(-1cm,0)$);
        % Drawing the + sign above the line
        \coordinate (C) at ($(A1-|B)+(0,0.2)$);
        \coordinate (D) at (\c,0);
        \node at (C-|D) {+};
      }
    }
  \else % Same as above
    \foreach \x in #3{
      \coordinate (A) at (#1);
      \coordinate (B) at (\x,0);
      \filldraw[fill=black,draw=black] (A-|B) circle(2pt)
        node[below]{\x};
      \foreach \c in {0.3,0.6,...,\x}{
        % Just drawing the - sign below
        \coordinate (C) at ($(A-|B)+(0,-0.2)$);
        \coordinate (D) at (\c,0);
        \node at (C-|D) {-};
      }
    }
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (A) at (5,0);
        \signplot{O}{A}{{0,3}}{0}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see I'm not handling the cases where there is more than 2 points since this happens

[image]

and in reality the sign should `+` above the line.

So if by chance there is an automatic way of "inverting" the sign and its position each time a new point is given, how would I do it? Also as you can see I am not handling not-in-domain points and drawing all of them black. As a side note, is there an automatic way of getting the sign of a function, given the function? It could be useful to have another command just for that.

Sorry if my explanation is not the best but I can't find the right words. Here is in the end what it should look like
[image]

Thanks for any help creating this command. I'm still quite new to command creation and conditionals so please, explain so I can do other things on my own. Thanks for reading.

---

**Edit:**
After some research and some help from @marmot , I created a function that does what I need, in the end. Here it is

```
\newcommand{\mysign}[1]{
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\tmpsign{sign(#1)}
    \ifnum\tmpsign<0
      -
    \else
      \ifnum\tmpsign>0
      +
      \else
      \relax
    \fi
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\drawSign}[6][]{% f(x) xmin xmax delta exclpoints
  \begin{scope}[#1,declare function={Test(\x) = #2;}]
    \draw [->, thick] (#3,0) -- (#4,0)node[right] {$x$};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\NextI}{#3+#5}
    \foreach \i in {#3,\NextI,...,#4}{
      \node at (\i,{0.35*sign(max(min(Test(\i),1),-1))}) {$\mysign{Test(\i)}$};
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\signum{sign(Test(\i))}
      \ifnum\signum=0
        \filldraw[black] (\i,0) circle(2pt);
        %\node[circle,fill,maximum size=2pt] at (\i,0){};
        \node[below] at (\i,-0.2){$\i$};
      \fi
    }
  \ifx&#6&%
  \else  
    % Excluded points
    \foreach \x in #6{
      \filldraw[fill=white,draw=black] (\x,0) circle(2pt);
      \node[below] at (\x,-0.2) {$\x$};
    }
  \fi
  \end{scope}
}
```

And now the plot for the function `\drawSign{(\x^2-5*\x+4)/(\x-5+0.001)}{-2}{7}{0.25}{5}` is

[image]

which is the desired result.

If there is an automatic way of knowing the zeroes of the function, it would be fantastic you shared it! Thanks for reading.

Comment: Related (not exactly what you're asking for, but might be of interest): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30588/defining-a-new-command-for-making-functional-lines-package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\mysign}[1]{\pgfmathtruncatemacro\tmpsign{sign(#1)}
\ifnum\tmpsign<0
-
\else\ifnum\tmpsign>0
+
\else
\relax
\fi
\fi
}




\begin{document}
The basic idea is to define a function that changes its signs at some locations.
Call the locations $x_1,\dots x_n$, then a convenient choice of the function is
\[ T(x)~=~\pm\prod\limits_{i=1}^n(x_i-x_n)\]
and this function is called \texttt{Test} in the snippet below. In addition, one
may want to introduce a function
\[ \backslash\texttt{mysign}(x)~=~\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
+ &\text{if}~x>0\;,\\
- &\text{if}~x<0\;,\\
\backslash\texttt{empty} & \text{if}~x=0\;.
\end{array}\right.\] 
Then one can simply plot the combination of these functions.\\[1cm]
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,
declare function={Test(\i) = \i*(3-\i)*(\i-4);}]
\draw [->, thick] (-2,0) -- (7.5,0)node[right] {$x$};
\foreach \i in {-2,-1.75,...,7}
{
\node at (\i,{0.35*sign(Test(\i))}) {$\mysign{Test(\i)}$};
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\signum{sign(Test(\i))}
\ifnum\signum=0
\node[circle,fill,minimum size=2pt] at (\i,0){};
\node[below] at (\i,-0.2){$\i$};
\fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}

One may also write a function for that, 
$\backslash\texttt{DrawSign}\{f(\backslash x)\}\{x_\mathrm{min}\}
\{x_\mathrm{max}\}\{\Delta x\}$, see below.\\[1cm]
\newcommand{\DrawSign}[5][]{\begin{scope}[#1,declare function={Test(\x) = #2;}]
\draw [->, thick] (#3,0) -- (#4,0)node[right] {$x$};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\NextI}{#3+#5}
\foreach \i in {#3,\NextI,...,#4}
{
\node at (\i,{0.35*sign(Test(\i))}) {$\mysign{Test(\i)}$};
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\signum{sign(Test(\i))}
\ifnum\signum=0
\node[circle,fill,minimum size=2pt] at (\i,0){};
\node[below] at (\i,-0.2){$\i$};
\fi
}
\end{scope}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\DrawSign[scale=1.5]{(\x-1)*(\x+3)}{-5}{3}{0.25}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Based on [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/406776/121799).

Comment: That looks great but I have a couple of more questions: if I wanted it to be a command I can run, how can I pass the function to the environment? Also, how can I distinguish in-domain points from the ones that are excluded? For example if your `Test` function became `\i*(\i-3)/(\i-4)` it would crash because `4` is not in the domain. I like then to change `|` to use filled/empty circles, as shown in the pictures. Thanks anyways for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: You may try passing the function by passing a `declare function` to a scope. But personally I would just pass the zeros and construct the function from it. Why would you want to use a singular function? (I'm not aware of any way to teach Ti*k*Z to deal with singularities other than throwing errors.) And I will fix the bullet.

Comment: I'm just used to making a method the most general possible. My ideal situation would be something along the lines of `\signplot{(3-x)/(1-x^2)+3x}` and it does all the work but I gather not being the easiest thing. Of course I could just pass the zeroes and then constructing the function. That i will do if there is no other way. And for the bullets and not-in-domain points, I gather either I catch the errors, if possible or find other manual ways.

Comment: @gjkf OK, I added a function. (I also tried to avoid singularities by wrapping the function into min and max like `max(min(Test(x),1),-1)`, but this didn't work, the function was, not surprisingly, evaluated first before getting cut. If you ever find a way, please let me know ;-)

Comment: That is just lovely! Many thanks! I will look deeper and try and find a way to detect singularities but I feel like it is not going to be easy. Thanks again for your awesome help!

Comment: So, after some tweaking around I found there is no easy solution to check if a point is in the domain. So what I did is a really dirty way of fixing this:
1. I added a new parameter for excluded points (the ones I know already) so I can draw the white points
2. I used your idea of `max(min(Test(x),1)-1)` and in the command call I just add `0.001` to the `x` in the denominator. This way I have something along the lines of `\drawSign{(\x^2-5*\x+4)/(\x-5+0.001)}{-2}{7}{0.25}{5}` and I obtain the correct sign plot. I'll edit the question and add the solution. Once again, thanks for all the help!